# Vocalizer voices provided by Nuance Speechkit

Tags: ios, speechkit

I am using Nuance Speechkit for speech vocalisation in my application. In demo application `SKVocalizer` is initialise with voice `@"Samantha"`

```
vocalizer = [[SKVocalizer alloc] initWithVoice:@"Samantha" delegate:self];
```

What are the other English(US) voices I can initialise it with?

Answer (score 0):

Nuance provide a good set of Vocaliser voices for several languages. You can check all those out at [Languages & Voices](https://developer.nuance.com/public/index.php?task=supportedLanguages) page of the documentation.

I am adding English and french one here for your references:

> ### Engish
>
> English (US)  en_US   eng-USA Ava F
>    English (US)   en_US   eng-USA Allison F
>    English (US)   en_US   eng-USA Samantha    F
>    English (US)   en_US   eng-USA Susan   F
>    English (US)   en_US   eng-USA Zoe F
>    English (US)   en_US   eng-USA Tom M
>
> ### French
>
> French fr_FR   fra-FRA Audrey-ML   F
>   French  fr_FR   fra-FRA Thomas  M
>   French  fr_FR   fra-FRA Aurelie F